# What database should I use to store video from android app?

Tags: android, mysql, azure, video

I want to make android/iOS app where people can record video and post it. 
I want to store those videos on my server and let other users to watch that. 
Only few of videos would be on my database so I don't need a lots of storage, but a lot of data transfer.
Can I use Azure SQL database for that purpose?
I want the one for 12,68Euro per month.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/

I don't want to store videos on Youtube because I want to make sharing as simple as possible.

Thanks for help.

Comment: There's no "right" answer to this question - any database can be used for storing your information. You might want to consider looking into things like blob storage, since that is designed for large-item storage, vs a database (which is typically optimized for searchable metadata, although databases like SQL Server / SQL Database *do* support BLOB types).

Answer (score 0):

As someone already pointed out, this is a question with no clear answer, but I would also suggest to use Azure Blob storage for this scenario. The first reason is because the Blob storage is optimized for file storage, will respond much quicker to requests for the file and also would be more convenient from a pricing perspective. [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-php-how-to-use-blobs) is a getting started guide for C++ (you can find there also guides for other languages).

If you need really quick responses, than [Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/introduction) would be also an option. However, I would recommend this for really large scale applications only.

According to the [Azure Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/), you would pay around 16$/month for 1 TB of storage (which I think is huge. If you have more, then maybe Cosmos DB would be useful).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

Check this blog and see Google Cloud pricing, if your requirements lie in its free package, then it's the best solution for you.

https://medium.com/@bkawk/in-search-of-free-or-cheap-database-storage-d6144ccfa42b

Comment: The question was about Azure, not Google.